# Extracting Urdu/Arabic phrases/sentences from a string

Tags: php, regex

I want to extract Urdu phrases out of a user-submitted string in PHP. For this, I tried the following test code:

```
$pattern = "#([\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]+\s*)+#u";
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    print_r($matches);
} else {
    echo 'No matches.';
}
```

Now if, for example, `$string` contains

`In his books (some of which include دنیا گول ہے, آوارہ گرد کی ڈائری, and ابن بطوطہ کے تعاقب میں), Ibn-e-Insha has told amusing stories of his travels.`

I get the following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => دنیا گول ہے
            [1] => ہے
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => آوارہ گرد کی ڈائری
            [1] => ڈائری
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ابن بطوطہ کے تعاقب میں
            [1] => میں
        )

)
```

Even though I get my desired matches (`دنیا گول ہے`, `آوارہ گرد کی ڈائری`, and `ابن بطوطہ کے تعاقب میں`), I also get undesired ones (`ہے`, `ڈائری`, and `میں` -- each of which is actually the last word of its phrase). Can anyone please point out how I can avoid the undesired matches?

Comment: That snippet with the Arrays looks cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the capturing group `([\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]+\s*)` is matched multiple times,each time overwriting what it matched the previous time.  You could get the expected output by simply converting it to a non-capturing group -- `(?:[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]+\s*)` -- but here's a more correct alternative:

```
$pattern = "#(?:[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]+(?:\s+[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]+)*)#u";
```

The first `[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]+` matches the first word, then *if* there's some whitespace followed by another word, `(?:\s+[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]+)*` matches it and any subsequent words.  But it doesn't match any whitespace after the last word, which I presume you don't want.

Comment: Thanks, Alan M. It works exactly as I wanted to. I'll read up more on non-capturing groups.