# Extracting Arabic words(not semantic arabic phrases) from a string

Tags: java, regex, locale

```
String description="Big data is a broad term for data sets so large or complex that traditional data processing applications are inadequate. البيانات الضخمة هي عبارة عن مجموعة من مجموعة البيانات الضخمة جداً والمعقدة لدرجة أنه يُصبح من الصعب معالجتها باستخدام أداة واحدة فقط من أدوات إدارة قواعد البيانات أو باستخدام تطبيقات معالجة البيانات التقليدية. "
```

I need a regex to extract only arabic words .

I check [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353741/extracting-urdu-arabic-phrases-sentences-from-a-string?rq=1) , however , it is a PHP ticket , while , i need JAVA regex  .

```
import java.util.regex.*;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#(?:[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]+(?:\s+[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]+)*)#u");
print(p.matcher(description).group(1));
```

It raises an error .

Comment: What error is raised?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi: Title? Yes. Content and answers? No. :-)

Comment: You need to escape backslashes in the pattern (\\\).

Comment: Step 1: Learn enough about the PHP regex you're trying to reuse to at least know to remove the delimiters from it. Step 2: Learn enough about Java regex enough to know that since you're putting the pattern in a string, you have to handle the fact that backslashes in strings are special and need special handling if you want the pattern to actually see them.

Comment: Maybe something [like this](http://ideone.com/Zirajn)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find one or more Arabic characters you can use `\p{InArabic}+`

This class is not mentioned directly by [Pattern documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), but it gives us informations about

> **Classes for Unicode scripts, blocks, categories and binary properties**
> `\p{IsLatin}`  A Latin script character ([script](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#usc))
> `\p{InGreek}`  A character in the Greek block ([block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#ubc))
> `\p{Lu}`   An uppercase letter ([category](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#ucc))
> `\p{IsAlphabetic}` An alphabetic character ([binary property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#ubpc))

and encouraged by example of `\p{InGreek}` we can start reading about blocks, to find that

> **Blocks** are specified with the prefix `In`, as in `InMongolian`, or by using the keyword `block` (or its short form `blk`) as in `block=Mongolian` or `blk=Mongolian`.
>
> The block names supported by `Pattern` are the valid block names accepted and defined by [`UnicodeBlock.forName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html#forName-java.lang.String-).

That last sentence is most important for us. Now we need to see if `UnicodeBlocks` should support group of Arabic characters. So we visit its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html) where we can find field

[`public static final Character.UnicodeBlock ARABIC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.UnicodeBlock.html#ARABIC)

which suggest that there is support for Arabic characters block.

---

So to find single Arabic words your code can look like:

```
String description="Big data is a broad term for data sets so large or complex that traditional data processing applications are inadequate. البيانات الضخمة هي عبارة عن مجموعة من مجموعة البيانات الضخمة جداً والمعقدة لدرجة أنه يُصبح من الصعب معالجتها باستخدام أداة واحدة فقط من أدوات إدارة قواعد البيانات أو باستخدام تطبيقات معالجة البيانات التقليدية. ";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{InArabic}+";
Matcher m = p.matcher(description);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

output:

```
البيانات
الضخمة
هي
.
.
.
البيانات
التقليدية
```

If you want to find groups of Arabic words separated by one or more whitespace you can this pattern

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\p{InArabic}+(?:\\s+\\p{InArabic}+)*");
```

You may want to know that `*` - represents zero or more, and `+` - one or more

So this regex means

```
\\p{InArabic}+     # one or more Arabic characters (Arabic word)
(?:                # non-capturing group storing:
  \\s+             # one or more whitespace characters
  \\p{InArabic}+   # with another Arabic word after it
)*                 # zero or more times
```